# What are all the possible entry points for cloning a record?

Tags: custom-object, clone

In an org I have worked on, we needed to stop users from being able to clone a custom object record. (it just doesn't fit the business logic).

To do this, I removed the "Clone" button from the page layout. Seemed like a nice easy fix. There was some issues with the button still appearing for System Admins(??) but that was fine as they could be trained appropriately.

It seems however that a user in a regular profile and role has managed to clone a record as part of their normal work (unfortunately about 10 days ago now and they "can't remember what they did"); so I am now hunting down a source of this functionality. Is there a "clone" button or link (perhaps in reports, list views?) I have missed. I have searched all the obvious places (like reports, list views, related lists). Any answers indicating the location of a Clone functionality will be warmly upvoted!

Comment: Not entirely answering your question, but maybe addressing your actual need: How about overriding the Clone view on the custom object with a VF page that says "Cloning of X is not allowed". Then it doesn't matter if they find a clever way to get to cloning. Combine that with removing obvious button (as you have already done) and you're good.

Comment: I believe that by URL hacking user can clone the record by putting https://ap2.salesforce.com/00328000002VO64/e?clone=1&nooverride=1.

Comment: @aidan that's a good idea. Have done that before to explain to users why/when they can't edit a specific record before. I will put this forward as an enhancement possibility

Comment: @Ashwani good point, I hope(!!) these users arn't poisoning their URLs, or they are in a world of trouble! but a fix like above would also kill channel off too anyway, right?

Comment: Overriding the `clone` button should solve 99% of of the problem but https://na12.salesforce.com/00328000002VO64/e?clone=1&nooverride=1 would always work and bypass the custom message.